# Tensorflow Object Detection API can't load .records file

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train object detection model by following [running locally](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) option from tensorflow object detection API. 
After following the documentation:

1. I am able to download the data and have placed pascal_train.record, pascal_eval.record and pascal_label_map.pbtxt in ./object_detection/data/ directory.
2. I have edited the "faster_rcnn_resnet101.config" and placed as : ./models/model/faster_rcnn_resnet101.config.
3. I did following changes in the .config file: fine_tune_checkpoint : model_path/model.ckpt, input_path = ./object_detection/data/pascal_train.record, label_map_path: ./object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt and similarly for eval_input_reader.
4. Now if I use following command to train the model : python3 object_detection/train.py --pipeline_config_path=./object_detection/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101.config --train_dir=./model/train_logs, it throws this error :

INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.

INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path ./model/train_logs/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.

INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , ~/Documents/Projects/models/object_detection/data/pascal_train.record

[[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2_2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2_2, parallel_read/filenames)]]

INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
2017-08-29 11:41:59.852783: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_5_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT3
2, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
2017-08-29 11:41:59.852819: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_5_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT3
2, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
2017-08-29 11:41:59.852797: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_5_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
.
.
.
.

[[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
2017-08-29 11:42:00.353191: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_5_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
2017-08-29 11:42:00.353105: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_5_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training.

INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 199, in 
    tf.app.run()

File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run

```
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
```

File "object_detection/train.py", line 195, in main

```
worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
```

File "/home/skulhare/Documents/Projects/models/object_detection

/trainer.py", line 296, in train

```
saver=saver)
```

File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 767, in train

```
sv.stop(threads, close_summary_writer=True)
```

File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 792, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)

File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)

File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run

```
enqueue_callable()
```

File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1235, in _single_operation_run
    target_list_as_strings, status, None)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in **exit**
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/skulhare/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ~/Documents/Projects/models/object_detection/data/pascal_train.record
         [[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2_2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2_2, parallel_read/filenames)]]

I have been using tensorflow 1.3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with GTX 1080 ti. 
[Here](https://github.com/skrealworld/Useful_Scripts/blob/master/faster_rcnn_resnet101.config) is the content of faster_rcnn_resnet101.config file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the contents of your faster_rcnn_resnet101.config?

Comment: Hi Derek, here is the link of config file : https://github.com/skrealworld/Useful_Scripts/blob/master/faster_rcnn_resnet101.config                            Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Try expanding `~/Documents/Projects/models/object_detection/data/pascal_train.record` (don't use the "~"; specify the full path)

Comment: Hmm, that did the magic, but I am wondering what problem "~/" is causing. Thanks a lot Derek.